# Modifying predicate expression for wrapping class

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I have a repository class that allows for queries using a lambda expression (simplified partial code):

```
public class SomeRepository<T>: IRepository<T> 
{
    public IList<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        return SomeQueryProvider.Where(filter).ToList();
    }
}
```

However, for a specific provider I have the need to wrap the original object in another class:

```
public class Wrapped<T>
{
    public T OriginalObject { get; set; }
}
```

So in this case, I also need to wrap the incoming predicate expression in another expression:

```
public class AnotherRepository<T>: IRepository<T> 
{
    public IList<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        Expression<Func<Wrapped<T>, bool>> wrappedFilter = ...
        return AnotherQueryProvider.Where(wrappedFilter).ToList();
    }
}
```

For example `x => x.ParentId == 123` should become `x => x.OriginalObject.ParentId == 123`.

I can't find examples for this scenario, and I'm having difficulty solving this myself. How can I prepend the predicate expression with the `OriginalObject` property?

Comment: What about selecting the `OriginalObject` and then use the `filter` as is: `AnotherQueryProvider.Select(x=>x.OriginalObjext).Where(filter).ToList();`

Comment: Actually there are a lot of examples if you search for [composing expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compose+expression), but as the other commenter mentioned, you could simply exchange the `Where` and `Select` (your sample should have `Select` in order to compile).

Comment: @OfirWinegarten thanks, for some reason I didn't think of the most simple solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the concrete question.

Given expression

```
Expression<Func<Wrapped<T>, T>> e1 = w => w.OriginalObject;
```

converting the expression

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> e2 = o => o.ParentId == 123;
```

to

```
Expression<Func<Wrapped<T>, T>> e3 = w => w.OriginalObject.ParentId == 123;
```

is a matter of replacing the `o` parameter occurrences inside the `e2` body with `w.OriginalObject` (the body of the `e1`). Something like string replace, but for expressions :)

First you need a method that replaces expression parameter with something else. Here is the one that I use:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{ 
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }
    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the method in question could be like this:

```
partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<Func<Wrapped<T>, TResult>> ToWrapped<T, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T, TResult>> source)
    {
        Expression<Func<Wrapped<T>, T>> unwrap = w => w.OriginalObject;
        var parameter = unwrap.Parameters[0];
        var body = source.Body.ReplaceParameter(source.Parameters[0], unwrap.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Wrapped<T>, TResult>>(body, parameter);
    }
}
```

and the usage

```
var wrappedFilter = filter.ToWrapped();
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it answers the question, even though the solution as given in the comments to the question is a better fit in this case.